# Having trouble copying an existing sqlite db file from assets to android project

Tags: java, android, sqlite, copy, assets

I have the following code:

```
private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
    Context context = this.getApplicationContext();

    // Open your local db as the input stream
    InputStream myInput = context.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

    // Define output file name
    File outfile = new File(context.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME).toString());
    outfile.setWritable(true);

    // Open the empty db as the output stream
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outfile);

    // transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    // Close the streams
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();
}
```

However, it keeps failing on the `OutputStream` variable. The error that keeps getting thrown is:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException ... mydb.db: open failed: ENOTDIR (Not a directory)
```

My SQLite file is in my assets directory in the project, and my `minSdkVersion` is `19` and `targetSdkVersion` is `28`.

This is an updated version of the function call from comments below, and it is still failing.

```
private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
    Context context = this.getApplicationContext();

    // Open your local db as the input stream
    InputStream myInput = context.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

    // Define output file name
    File outfile = new File(context.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME).toString());

    try {
        // Define path to database file and make directories if necessary
        File dir = new File(DB_PATH);
        if (!dir.exists()) {
            boolean madeDirectory = dir.mkdirs();
            Log.d(TAG, String.format("copyDataBase: Made directories: %s", madeDirectory));
        }

        if (!outfile.exists()){
            outfile.createNewFile();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Open the empty db as the output stream
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outfile);

    // transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    // Close the streams
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();
}
```

The variable `DB_NAME` is merely the name of the database file I am using, `myExample.db`

The string generated from the getDatabasePath function call is `"/data/data/projectname/databases/myExample.db`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that your issue is that the databases folder doesn't exist. Rather just `/data/data/<the_package>/` exists.

So try adding the code as per the comments :-

```
File outfile = new File(context.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME).toString()); //<<<<<<<<< EXISTING LINE
if (!outfile.getParentFile().exists()) { //<<<<<<<<<< ADDED
    outfile.getParentFile().mkdirs(); //<<<<<<<<<< ADDED
} //<<<<<<<<<< ADDED
```

I tend do the directory creation in when checking to see if the database exists e.g. :-

```
private boolean checkDataBase() {
    /**
     * Does not open the database instead checks to see if the file exists
     * also creates the databases directory if it does not exist
     * (the real reason why the database is opened, which appears to result in issues)
     */

    File db = new File(myContext.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME).getPath()); //Get the file name of the database
    if (db.exists()) return true; // If it exists then return doing nothing

    // Get the parent (directory in which the database file would be)
    File dbdir = db.getParentFile();
    // If the directory does not exist then make the directory (and higher level directories if need be)
    if (!dbdir.exists()) {
        dbdir.mkdirs();
    }
    return false;
}
```

## Replicating the Issue

Using the code  :-

```
private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {

        final String TAG = "COPYDATABASE";

        //Open your local db as the input stream
        Log.d(TAG,"Initiated Copy of the database file " + DB_NAME + " from the assets folder.");
        InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME); // Open the Asset file
        String dbpath = myContext.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME).getPath();
        Log.d(TAG,"Asset file " + DB_NAME + " found so attmepting to copy to " + dbpath);

        // Path to the just created empty db
        //String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        //Open the empty db as the output stream
        File outfile = new File(myContext.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME).toString());
        Log.d("DBPATH","path is " + outfile.getPath());
        outfile.setWritable(true);
        //OutputStream myoutputx2 = new FileOutputStream(outfile);
        if (!outfile.getParentFile().exists()) {
            outfile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        }

        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outfile);
        //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
        byte[] buffer = new byte[buffer_size];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0) {
            blocks_copied++;
            Log.d(TAG,"Ateempting copy of block " + String.valueOf(blocks_copied) + " which has " + String.valueOf(length) + " bytes.");
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
            bytes_copied += length;
        }
        Log.d(TAG,
                "Finished copying Database " + DB_NAME +
                        " from the assets folder, to  " + dbpath +
                        String.valueOf(bytes_copied) + "were copied, in " +
                        String.valueOf(blocks_copied) + " blocks of size " +
                        String.valueOf(buffer_size) + "."
        );
        //Close the streams
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();
        Log.d(TAG,"All Streams have been flushed and closed.");
    }
```

Results in the error you are getting as per :-

```
02-21 10:17:25.975 7604-7604/so.cdfa D/VERSION: Build Version is 22
02-21 10:17:25.975 7604-7604/so.cdfa D/DBPATH: DB Path is /data/data/so.cdfa/databases/db
02-21 10:17:25.975 7604-7604/so.cdfa D/DBPATH: DB Path is /data/data/so.cdfa/databases/db
02-21 10:17:25.976 7604-7604/so.cdfa D/COPYDATABASE: Initiated Copy of the database file db from the assets folder.
02-21 10:17:25.976 7604-7604/so.cdfa D/COPYDATABASE: Asset file db found so attmepting to copy to /data/data/so.cdfa/databases/db
02-21 10:17:25.976 7604-7604/so.cdfa D/DBPATH: path is /data/data/so.cdfa/databases/db
02-21 10:17:25.976 7604-7604/so.cdfa W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/so.cdfa/databases/db: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
02-21 10:17:25.976 7604-7604/so.cdfa W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:456)
02-21 10:17:25.976 7604-7604/so.cdfa W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:87)
02-21 10:17:25.976 7604-7604/so.cdfa W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:72)
02-21 10:17:25.976 7604-7604/so.cdfa W/System.err:     at so.cdfa.DBHelper.copyDataBase(DBHelper.java:120)
02-21 10:17:25.976 7604-7604/so.cdfa W/System.err:     at so.cdfa.DBHelper.createDataBase(DBHelper.java:58)
02-21 10:17:25.976 7604-7604/so.cdfa W/System.err:     at so.cdfa.DBHelper.<init>(DBHelper.java:32)
02-21 10:17:25.976 7604-7604/so.cdfa W/System.err:     at so.cdfa.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:60)
02-21 10:17:25.976 7604-7604/so.cdfa W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
02-21 10:17:25.976 7604-7604/so.cdfa W/System.err:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
02-21 10:17:25.976 7604-7604/so.cdfa W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
02-21 10:17:25.976 7604-7604/so.cdfa W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
02-21 10:17:25.976 7604-7604/so.cdfa W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
02-21 10:17:25.977 7604-7604/so.cdfa W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
02-21 10:17:25.977 7604-7604/so.cdfa W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
02-21 10:17:25.977 7604-7604/so.cdfa W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
02-21 10:17:25.977 7604-7604/so.cdfa W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
02-21 10:17:25.977 7604-7604/so.cdfa W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
02-21 10:17:25.977 7604-7604/so.cdfa W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
02-21 10:17:25.977 7604-7604/so.cdfa W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
02-21 10:17:25.977 7604-7604/so.cdfa W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
02-21 10:17:25.977 7604-7604/so.cdfa W/System.err: Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
02-21 10:17:25.977 7604-7604/so.cdfa W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
02-21 10:17:25.977 7604-7604/so.cdfa W/System.err:     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
02-21 10:17:25.977 7604-7604/so.cdfa W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:442)
02-21 10:17:25.977 7604-7604/so.cdfa W/System.err:  ... 19 more
02-21 10:17:25.977 7604-7604/so.cdfa D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
02-21 10:17:25.977 7604-7604/so.cdfa E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: so.cdfa, PID: 7604
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{so.cdfa/so.cdfa.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error copying database (see stack-trace above)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error copying database (see stack-trace above)
        at so.cdfa.DBHelper.createDataBase(DBHelper.java:65)
```

Amending the code to (as per the original answer):-

```
private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {

    final String TAG = "COPYDATABASE";

    //Open your local db as the input stream
    Log.d(TAG,"Initiated Copy of the database file " + DB_NAME + " from the assets folder.");
    InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME); // Open the Asset file
    String dbpath = myContext.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME).getPath();
    Log.d(TAG,"Asset file " + DB_NAME + " found so attmepting to copy to " + dbpath);

    // Path to the just created empty db
    //String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    //Open the empty db as the output stream
    File outfile = new File(myContext.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME).toString());
    Log.d("DBPATH","path is " + outfile.getPath());
    outfile.setWritable(true); //<<<<<<<<<< not required as writable access exists
    //OutputStream myoutputx2 = new FileOutputStream(outfile);
    if (!outfile.getParentFile().exists()) {
        outfile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
    }

    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outfile);
    //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
    byte[] buffer = new byte[buffer_size];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0) {
        blocks_copied++;
        Log.d(TAG,"Ateempting copy of block " + String.valueOf(blocks_copied) + " which has " + String.valueOf(length) + " bytes.");
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        bytes_copied += length;
    }
    Log.d(TAG,
            "Finished copying Database " + DB_NAME +
                    " from the assets folder, to  " + dbpath +
                    String.valueOf(bytes_copied) + "were copied, in " +
                    String.valueOf(blocks_copied) + " blocks of size " +
                    String.valueOf(buffer_size) + "."
    );
    //Close the streams
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();
    Log.d(TAG,"All Streams have been flushed and closed.");
}
```

Results in :-

```
02-21 10:24:31.808 7972-7972/? D/VERSION: Build Version is 22
02-21 10:24:31.808 7972-7972/? D/DBPATH: DB Path is /data/data/so.cdfa/databases/db
02-21 10:24:31.808 7972-7972/? D/DBPATH: DB Path is /data/data/so.cdfa/databases/db
02-21 10:24:31.808 7972-7972/? D/COPYDATABASE: Initiated Copy of the database file db from the assets folder.
02-21 10:24:31.808 7972-7972/? D/COPYDATABASE: Asset file db found so attmepting to copy to /data/data/so.cdfa/databases/db
02-21 10:24:31.808 7972-7972/? D/DBPATH: path is /data/data/so.cdfa/databases/db
02-21 10:24:31.809 7972-7972/? D/COPYDATABASE: Ateempting copy of block 1 which has 1024 bytes.
02-21 10:24:31.809 7972-7972/? D/COPYDATABASE: Ateempting copy of block 2 which has 1024 bytes.
02-21 10:24:31.809 7972-7972/? D/COPYDATABASE: Ateempting copy of block 3 which has 1024 bytes.
02-21 10:24:31.809 7972-7972/? D/COPYDATABASE: Ateempting copy of block 4 which has 1024 bytes.
02-21 10:24:31.809 7972-7972/? D/COPYDATABASE: Ateempting copy of block 5 which has 1024 bytes.
02-21 10:24:31.809 7972-7972/? D/COPYDATABASE: Ateempting copy of block 6 which has 1024 bytes.
02-21 10:24:31.809 7972-7972/? D/COPYDATABASE: Ateempting copy of block 7 which has 1024 bytes.
02-21 10:24:31.809 7972-7972/? D/COPYDATABASE: Ateempting copy of block 8 which has 1024 bytes.
02-21 10:24:31.809 7972-7972/? D/COPYDATABASE: Ateempting copy of block 9 which has 1024 bytes.
02-21 10:24:31.810 7972-7972/? D/COPYDATABASE: Ateempting copy of block 10 which has 1024 bytes.
02-21 10:24:31.810 7972-7972/? D/COPYDATABASE: Ateempting copy of block 11 which has 1024 bytes.
02-21 10:24:31.810 7972-7972/? D/COPYDATABASE: Ateempting copy of block 12 which has 1024 bytes.
02-21 10:24:31.810 7972-7972/? D/COPYDATABASE: Ateempting copy of block 13 which has 1024 bytes.
02-21 10:24:31.810 7972-7972/? D/COPYDATABASE: Ateempting copy of block 14 which has 1024 bytes.
02-21 10:24:31.810 7972-7972/? D/COPYDATABASE: Ateempting copy of block 15 which has 1024 bytes.
02-21 10:24:31.810 7972-7972/? D/COPYDATABASE: Ateempting copy of block 16 which has 1024 bytes.
02-21 10:24:31.810 7972-7972/? D/COPYDATABASE: Ateempting copy of block 17 which has 1024 bytes.
02-21 10:24:31.810 7972-7972/? D/COPYDATABASE: Ateempting copy of block 18 which has 1024 bytes.
02-21 10:24:31.810 7972-7972/? D/COPYDATABASE: Ateempting copy of block 19 which has 1024 bytes.
02-21 10:24:31.810 7972-7972/? D/COPYDATABASE: Ateempting copy of block 20 which has 1024 bytes.
02-21 10:24:31.810 7972-7972/? D/COPYDATABASE: Ateempting copy of block 21 which has 1024 bytes.
02-21 10:24:31.810 7972-7972/? D/COPYDATABASE: Ateempting copy of block 22 which has 1024 bytes.
02-21 10:24:31.810 7972-7972/? D/COPYDATABASE: Ateempting copy of block 23 which has 1024 bytes.
02-21 10:24:31.810 7972-7972/? D/COPYDATABASE: Ateempting copy of block 24 which has 1024 bytes.
02-21 10:24:31.811 7972-7972/? D/COPYDATABASE: Ateempting copy of block 25 which has 1024 bytes.
02-21 10:24:31.811 7972-7972/? D/COPYDATABASE: Ateempting copy of block 26 which has 1024 bytes.
02-21 10:24:31.811 7972-7972/? D/COPYDATABASE: Ateempting copy of block 27 which has 1024 bytes.
02-21 10:24:31.811 7972-7972/? D/COPYDATABASE: Ateempting copy of block 28 which has 1024 bytes.
02-21 10:24:31.811 7972-7972/? D/COPYDATABASE: Ateempting copy of block 29 which has 1024 bytes.
02-21 10:24:31.811 7972-7972/? D/COPYDATABASE: Ateempting copy of block 30 which has 1024 bytes.
02-21 10:24:31.811 7972-7972/? D/COPYDATABASE: Ateempting copy of block 31 which has 1024 bytes.
02-21 10:24:31.811 7972-7972/? D/COPYDATABASE: Ateempting copy of block 32 which has 1024 bytes.
02-21 10:24:31.811 7972-7972/? D/COPYDATABASE: Ateempting copy of block 33 which has 1024 bytes.
02-21 10:24:31.811 7972-7972/? D/COPYDATABASE: Ateempting copy of block 34 which has 1024 bytes.
02-21 10:24:31.811 7972-7972/? D/COPYDATABASE: Ateempting copy of block 35 which has 1024 bytes.
02-21 10:24:31.811 7972-7972/? D/COPYDATABASE: Ateempting copy of block 36 which has 1024 bytes.
02-21 10:24:31.811 7972-7972/? D/COPYDATABASE: Ateempting copy of block 37 which has 1024 bytes.
02-21 10:24:31.811 7972-7972/? D/COPYDATABASE: Ateempting copy of block 38 which has 1024 bytes.
02-21 10:24:31.812 7972-7972/? D/COPYDATABASE: Ateempting copy of block 39 which has 1024 bytes.
02-21 10:24:31.812 7972-7972/? D/COPYDATABASE: Ateempting copy of block 40 which has 1024 bytes.
02-21 10:24:31.812 7972-7972/? D/COPYDATABASE: Finished copying Database db from the assets folder, to  /data/data/so.cdfa/databases/db40960were copied, in 40 blocks of size 1024.
02-21 10:24:31.812 7972-7972/? D/COPYDATABASE: All Streams have been flushed and closed.
```

### Entire DBHelper the above code was extracted from

- Logs would be removed and many comments were commentary and fixing a problem i.e. the code could be cleaned up.

:-

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static String DB_NAME = "db";
    private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;
    private final Context myContext;

    private int bytes_copied = 0;
    private static int buffer_size = 1024;
    private int blocks_copied = 0;

    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);

        this.myContext = context;
        // Check for and create (copy DB from assets) when constructing the DBHelper
        if (!checkDataBase()) {
            bytes_copied = 0;
            blocks_copied = 0;
            createDataBase();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Creates an empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own database.
     * */
    public void createDataBase() {

        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase(); // Double check
        if(dbExist){
            //do nothing - database already exist
        } else {
            //By calling this method an empty database will be created into the default system path
            //of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that database with our database.
            //this.getReadableDatabase();
            //<<<<<<<<<< Dimsiss the above comment
            //By calling this method an empty database IS NOT created nor are the related -shm and -wal files
            //The method that creates the database is flawed and was only used to resolve the issue
            //of the copy failing in the absence of the databases directory.
            //The dbExist method, now utilised, checks for and creates the database directory, so there
            //is then no need to create the database just to create the databases library. As a result
            //the -shm and -wal files will not exist and thus result in the error associated with
            //Android 9+ failing with due to tables not existining after an apparently successful
            //copy.
            try {
                copyDataBase();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                File db = new File(myContext.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME).getPath());
                if (db.exists()) {
                    db.delete();
                }
                e.printStackTrace();
                throw new RuntimeException("Error copying database (see stack-trace above)");
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each time you open the application.
     * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
     */
    private boolean checkDataBase() {
        /**
         * Does not open the database instead checks to see if the file exists
         * also creates the databases directory if it does not exists
         * (the real reason why the database is opened, which appears to result in issues)
         */

        File db = new File(myContext.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME).getPath()); //Get the file name of the database
        Log.d("DBPATH","DB Path is " + db.getPath());
        if (db.exists()) return true; // If it exists then return doing nothing

        // Get the parent (directory in which the database file would be)
        File dbdir = db.getParentFile();
        // If the directory does not exits then make the directory (and higher level directories)
        /*
        if (!dbdir.exists()) {
            db.getParentFile().mkdirs();
            dbdir.mkdirs();
        }
        */
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created empty database in the
     * system folder, from where it can be accessed and handled.
     * This is done by transfering bytestream.
     * */
    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {

        final String TAG = "COPYDATABASE";

        //Open your local db as the input stream
        Log.d(TAG,"Initiated Copy of the database file " + DB_NAME + " from the assets folder.");
        InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME); // Open the Asset file
        String dbpath = myContext.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME).getPath();
        Log.d(TAG,"Asset file " + DB_NAME + " found so attmepting to copy to " + dbpath);

        // Path to the just created empty db
        //String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        //Open the empty db as the output stream
        File outfile = new File(myContext.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME).toString());
        Log.d("DBPATH","path is " + outfile.getPath());
        //outfile.setWritable(true); // NOT NEEDED as permission already applies
        //OutputStream myoutputx2 = new FileOutputStream(outfile);
        /* Note done in checkDatabase method
        if (!outfile.getParentFile().exists()) {
            outfile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        }
        */

        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outfile);
        //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
        byte[] buffer = new byte[buffer_size];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0) {
            blocks_copied++;
            Log.d(TAG,"Ateempting copy of block " + String.valueOf(blocks_copied) + " which has " + String.valueOf(length) + " bytes.");
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
            bytes_copied += length;
        }
        Log.d(TAG,
                "Finished copying Database " + DB_NAME +
                        " from the assets folder, to  " + dbpath +
                        String.valueOf(bytes_copied) + "were copied, in " +
                        String.valueOf(blocks_copied) + " blocks of size " +
                        String.valueOf(buffer_size) + "."
        );
        //Close the streams
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();
        Log.d(TAG,"All Streams have been flushed and closed.");
    }


    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {
        if(myDataBase != null)
            myDataBase.close();
        super.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigure(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        super.onConfigure(db);
        Log.d("DBCONFIGURE","Database has been configured ");
    }

    @Override
    public void onOpen(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        super.onOpen(db);
        Log.d("DBOPENED","Database has been opened.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Nope. Still doesn't work. I still get FileNotFoundException /data/data/...myDb.db: open failed: ENOTDIR (Not a directory)

Comment: @Jasonca1 can you edit your question to include the stack-trace, after adding the line `Log.d("DBPATH","DB Path is " + outfile.getPath());` immediately after the line `File outfile = new File(context.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME).toString());`.

Comment: the log output is: /data/data/com.myproject.myprojectpackage/databases/mydatabase.db

Comment: @Jasonca1 I believe you didn't properly introduce the directory creation code, perhaps you left of the **!**?. The answer has been amended to show codes that replicates your issue and that the fix works. *(not it's not the cleanest code as it's a adaption of existing code I have used (for another answer I gave))*

Comment: I will attempt your amended solution and post my results.

Comment: You nailed it on the second submission. Thank you very very much. Would there be an elegant way to check for the existence of this database file and then create it if it doesn't exist? I was thinking of just using this.getDatabasePath("myDatabase.db") and if it returns false, then run the copyDatabase function. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: IMO **NO**!!!!! You will see many that use SQLiteDatabase's **openOrCreate** (to get around this directory not existing issue). For Anroid Pie+ this causes issues as the default is Write Ahead Logging (WAL) was Journal mode. This creates -wal and -shm files, which complicates matters (in fact the above code was from answering such a question). Suggest you look at the checkDatabase method in the answer. Will add the full DBhelper code (it does the check) so you just need to instantiate the helper.

Comment: Roger that man. Thank you very much for the help. I greatly appreciate it. Breath of fresh air from the usual lack of response/ getting flamed for a posted question that can sometimes be StackOverflow. Again, thank you very much.

Comment: @Jasonca1 My Pleasure

Comment: A great explanation along with the code @MikeT. Kudos!

Answer (score 1):

The error says it could not find the output file. Hence you need to create one first in order to open that and copy from the asset.

```
try {       
    String DB_PATH = "/data/data/" + "your.application.package.name" + "/databases/";
    File dir = new File(DB_PATH);
    if (!dir.exists()) dir.mkdir();
    File f = new File(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);
    if (!f.exists()) {
        f.createNewFile();
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

// Then it should work
OutputStream mOutput = new FileOutputStream(f);
```

Comment: It's failing at the createNewFile function call

Comment: It should not. It might show an error that, this code segment can throw an error which can be easily avoided by using a try/catch block. I am updating the answer with a `try/catch` block. Please have a look.

Comment: @Raez Murshed It's still failing. Still getting an error code: java.io.IOException: open failed: ENOTDIR (Not a directory)

Comment: Can you please update the question with the code segment of your output directory? So that I could take a look? And what is your application package name?